# Android - copy entire directory including symlink

Tags: android, root, su, superuser

I'm trying to copy an applications entire data directory,
I'm using the following su command:

```
String sBackupData = "cp -rp /data/data/<app-name> /data/sdext2/backup/";
```

this copies & retains file permissions/ownership, however I am unable to successfully copy the .lib symlink.
Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: At this point I've decided on a temporary fix by creating a string array containing the handles of each directory. I then iterate through the array copying/deleting as necessary, this leaves the symbolic directory link in place, which is "okay". But still, I would prefer to copy the directories & symlink in one statement if at all possible.